# What does the set of dominant integral elements in a Cartan sub algebra look like?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

I'm reading about the theorem of the highest weight:  Irreducible finite dimensional representations of a complex semisimple Lie algebra (with a fixed Cartan sub algebra, $\frak{h}$ and choice of positive roots in the root system $\Delta(\frak g, h)$) correspond bijectively to elements $\lambda\in \frak{h}^\ast$ which are dominant (meaning $\langle\lambda, \alpha\rangle\geq 0$ for every positive element $\alpha \in \Delta$)  and algebraically integral (meaning $\frac{2\langle \lambda, \alpha \rangle}{|\alpha|^2} \in \mathbb{Z}$ for all $\alpha \in \Delta$).  What does this subset of $\frak{h}^\ast$ look like?  Evidently it is a discrete semigroup. Does it have a natural basis?

Comment: The natural basis is given by the fundamental weights (the elements dual to the simple roots).

Comment: @AndreasCap Thanks!

Comment: Well, each group is a different case. As pointed out by Andreas, yes, there is a basis, but it could be very hard to figure out in general what does this set look like. Usually there are answers for low dimensional "easy" examples such as $SU(n)$, $n < 6$, but it would be much harder to figure them out for $SU(n, m)$, for arbitrary $n, m$.